# How to select all rows that are related to satisfied condition in ms ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following data in table VehiclesAccSummary:

[image]

I am not sure how to do this but what I want is a query that would return all rows where there where only two car in the accident and it was a head on crash so in both cars PointOfImpact was 'Front' i know in need to do some inner join on the same table but i don' want to join same car with it self.  Any idea ?

The end result should be something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery to count the number of "Front' records for each AccRef.

```
   SELECT *
   FROM VehiclesAccSummary INNER JOIN
        (SELECT VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef, Count(VehiclesAccSummary.PointOfImpact) AS CountOfPointOfImpact FROM VehiclesAccSummary GROUP BY VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef, VehiclesAccSummary.PointOfImpact HAVING VehiclesAccSummary.PointOfImpact="Front")  AS FrontCount
   ON VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef = FrontCount.AccRef
   WHERE VehiclesAccSummary.NumCars = 2 AND CountOfPointOfImpact = 2;
```

This will limit the records to AccRefs with NumCar = 2 and the count of Front records = 2.

**Edit**: Since the same car can be listed in multiple records, we need a new approach. Try this:

```
SELECT VehiclesAccSummary.*, Subquery.CountOfPointOfImpact
FROM VehiclesAccSummary LEFT JOIN (SELECT VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef, Count(VehiclesAccSummary.PointOfImpact) AS CountOfPointOfImpact
FROM VehiclesAccSummary
WHERE (((VehiclesAccSummary.PointOfImpact)<>"Front"))
GROUP BY VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef) AS Subquery ON VehiclesAccSummary.AccRef = Subquery.AccRef
WHERE (((Subquery.CountOfPointOfImpact) Is Null));
```

Instead of confirming that the count of front accidents is 2, this confirms that the count of non-front accidents is 0.

Comment: i get a popup in ms access 'Enter Parameter Value' for CountfPointofImpact, this query will also return record where another car involved in accident may not be front impacted.

Comment: Sorry. There was a typo in the last line. It should say `CountOfPointOfImpact` not `CountfPointofImpact`. Try it now. As for your second concern, I don't think that's the case.  If the count of Front records is 2 AND the number of cars in the accident is 2, then it follows that there can't be any non-front records for that accident.

Comment: After fixing typo the poup is gone but i still get non 'front' matches

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p5TjuNc but i think it's because this table will return many rows for given car as there are many casualties per accident so we can have like 6 rows that are all 'front' impact for one car and that passes the CountOfPointOfImpact  check but the other car can be anything then. So the logic should not count PointOfImpact's but make sure that there is no other impact than 'front' instead maybe ?

Comment: @IronHide your example data didn't have any cases with multiple rows for multiple causualties, so I didn't know that would be a problem. No worries. Take a look at the revised answer. Also, you might want to look into table normalization if you haven't already. https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html.

Comment: Awesome that works, yeah i know about the  normalization thing but this is just my side project and I will not come back to database stuff in a long time. But thanks again.